# xcode 4.5.2 header search path problems

Tags: xcode, search, header, path

I've been working with Xcode 4.5.2 for several weeks and have found that the header search paths present the most difficult problems to solve. At the moment I'm working on an OpenFrameworks project and am typing '#include "UIImage.h"' into the testApp.h file. Xcode says it cannot find the UIImage.h file. I've found the path of the file and added it to the Header Search Paths and to the User Header Search Paths:

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/

Still does not find the file. I've read numerous posts here about this problem and tried to implement some of the solutions, but to no avail. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: OK - when I now put #include "UIKit/UIImage.h", all is well. But why is this necessary"

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18163321/xcodebuild-cannot-find-header-in-embedded-projects/19284935#19284935). Try using something like `"#include <Foundation/UIImage.h>"`. I've been fighting with xCode search paths as well. Here are two observations:

1. If you need to include your own headers, make sure that these are copied first (see the other post for steps).
2. Check the order inside "build phases" and make sure that the copying happens before compiling your sources.