# xcodebuild cannot find header in embedded projects

Tags: xcode

I have a project embed another project, and the xcode GUI build was successful, but in command line xcodebuild failed as such.

```
   fatal error: 'OHAttributedLabel/OHAttributedLabel.h' file not found
   #import <OHAttributedLabel/OHAttributedLabel.h>
           ^
   1 error generated.
```

but I had this in the project HEADER SEARCH PATH (where the h is located)

```
   ${PROJECT_DIR}/MyProject/Vendor/OHAttributedLabel/Source
```

the problem is the header is located in the "OHAttributedLabel/Source" folder, while the import statement is looking for header under OHAttributedLabel folder, I don't want to touch the embedded project directory structure, what can I do in this case?

Comment: Import `OHAttributedLabel/Source/OHAttributedLabel.h`.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to modify the embedded project to publish the header files:

1. Select the embedded project in xCode
2. Select the applicable target.
3. Click on the build phases
4. Expand "Copy Headers" section and add OHAttributedLabel.h file.
5. Select your main project
6. Select the applicable target.
7. Click on build phases.
8. Click on Target dependencies.
9. Make sure that the embedded project is added as a dependency.
10. Try to run the app

If the above doesn't work double-check the order of the build phases. E.g. make sure that the "Target Dependencies" build phase is before "Compile sources".